# EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError and "Error connecting with SSL. error:14094410..."

Tags: macos, delphi, openssl, indy

I have a problem with Indy components in Delphi 10.1 Berlin on OS X. I'm using `TIdHTTP` to connect to a webservice using HTTPS. The problem is connecting to a server from an OS X client. When running on OS X, I get this same error all the time:

```
Project raised exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting 
with SSL. error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure'.
```

I set the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property to use OpenSSL:

```
IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
```

On OS X, when I run this command in a terminal:

> openssl version

It returns OpenSSL 0.9, which is the default version that comes with OS X.

Even if I install the latest version of OpenSSL using Homebrew or MacPort, it does not help.  It give me the same error every time.

I have OS X installed in VMWare, if this helps. I also tried two versions of OS X: Yosemite and El Capitan.  Same problem.

This is code I use:

```
unit uApiClient1;

interface

uses
  IdHTTP, System.JSON, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders, System.Classes, IdCTypes,
  System.SysUtils, IdSSLOpenSSL;

const
  API_URL = 'https://www.myserver.com/ws.php';
  WS_METHOD = 'validate_status';

type
  TAPIClient = class(TObject)
    function ValidateStatus(userId, deviceId: string): TJSONObject;
  private
    procedure PrepareHTTPObject(var IdHTTP: TIdHTTP);
  end;


implementation

{ APIClient }

procedure TAPIClient.PrepareHTTPObject(var IdHTTP: TIdHTTP);
begin
  IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IdHTTP.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  //
  IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/javascript';
  IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
end;

function TAPIClient.ValidateStatus(userId, deviceId: string): TJSONObject;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  LJSONObject: TJSONObject;
  dataResult: string;
begin
  LJSONObject := nil;
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    try
      PrepareHTTPObject(IdHTTP);
      dataResult := IdHTTP.Get(API_URL + format('?action=%s&user_id=%s&device_id=%s', [WS_METHOD, userId, deviceid]));
      LJSONObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataResult), 0) as TJSONObject;
    except
    end;
  finally
   IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
  Result := LJSONObject;
end;

end.
```

---

I tried to compare packets from WireShark generated by my application and by Safari and this is what I get:

My application:

```
Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
    Length: 114
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Random
        GMT Unix Time: Aug 24, 2016 20:26:07.000000000 EEST
        Random Bytes: 49c48ba758048a2429dd01ee2e390ed06eb320e5248d016d...
    Session ID Length: 0
    Cipher Suites Length: 46
    Cipher Suites (23 suites)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009a)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0099)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0096)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0015)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0012)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0009)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0014)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0011)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0008)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5 (0x0006)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
    Compression Methods Length: 1
    Compression Methods (1 method)
    Extensions Length: 27
    Extension: server_name
    Extension: SessionTicket TLS
        Type: SessionTicket TLS (0x0023)
        Length: 0
        Data (0 bytes)
```

Safari browser:

```
Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
    Length: 229
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Random
        GMT Unix Time: Aug 24, 2016 20:35:07.000000000 EEST
        Random Bytes: d0f0bc116fd51dff15c739bb76f7e6032a931d07e2e56a56...
    Session ID Length: 0
    Cipher Suites Length: 44
    Cipher Suites (22 suites)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
    Compression Methods Length: 1
    Compression Methods (1 method)
    Extensions Length: 144
    Extension: server_name
    Extension: elliptic_curves
    Extension: ec_point_formats
    Extension: signature_algorithms
        Type: signature_algorithms (0x000d)
        Length: 14
        Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 12
        Signature Hash Algorithms (6 algorithms)
    Extension: next_protocol_negotiation
        Type: next_protocol_negotiation (0x3374)
        Length: 0
    Extension: Application Layer Protocol Negotiation
        Type: Application Layer Protocol Negotiation (0x0010)
        Length: 48
        ALPN Extension Length: 46
        ALPN Protocol
    Extension: status_request
        Type: status_request (0x0005)
        Length: 5
        Certificate Status Type: OCSP (1)
        Responder ID list Length: 0
        Request Extensions Length: 0
    Extension: signed_certificate_timestamp
        Type: signed_certificate_timestamp (0x0012)
        Length: 0
        Data (0 bytes)
```

In protocol column of the WireShark, for Savari is `TLSv1.2`, and for my application is `TLSv1`, even I set method to `sslvTLSv1_2` in code.

For both SNI is set correctly.

---

This is TLS alert from WireShark:

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 2
        Alert Message
            Level: Fatal (2)
            Description: Handshake Failure (40)
```

Comment: If this can hep:
when run in terminal command:

`openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect myserver.com:443`

I receive the same error, but when I run this command:

`openssl s_client -tls1_2 -servername myserver.com -connect myserver.com:443`

all is ok, it is connected without any error.

What I need to configure in Indy component to have the same call of the openSSL library?

Comment: What Indy version do you use exactly? Did you set TLS in `SSLOptions.Method`? Download latest version from `https://indy.fulgan.com/` because there were some problems with SNI (Server Name Indication). Or you can manually call `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875664/eidosslunderlyingcryptoerror-exception

Comment: Make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy. The current version [supports client-side SNI](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20160110B.aspx) and will call `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name()` for you.

Comment: I use Indy 10.6.2.5341 that comes with XE 10.1.
I tryed to set different SSLOptions.Method, but without any luck.
As I see, Indy call function you mentiond: SSL_set_tlsext_host_name, but anyway always give me error

Comment: Your error shows that it uses SSL3. Make sure that it really uses TLS.

Comment: I set TLS like this:

    `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IdHTTP.IOHandler).SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IdHTTP.IOHandler).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];`

Comment: @smooty86: In [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875664/eidosslunderlyingcryptoerror-exception) you said you solved it using SSL_set_tlsext_host_name, but how? I tryed solution provided by Nick C from your question, but it does not helped. Can you advice me? I'm confused, because on Windows I never have such problem. It is only on OS X

Comment: It seems you use up-to-date Indy version. You don't need to provide SNI anymore. I used `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(AsslSocket, AsslSocket.tlsext_hostname);` (if you want to try). Focus on the SSL method. You should not set both Method and SSLVersion (one changes the other). Just method is fine. Make sure that Indy does not load old system libraries. I don't know what priority is there - it should definitely not return "sslv3" error.

Comment: Since you are able to connect using the command-line `openssl.exe` tool, I suggest you use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to compare the tool's handshake versus Indy's handshake to see what is different between them. Wireshark can show you all of the handshake details.

Comment: @Remy - Can you tell Oleg how to remove SSLv2 and SSLv3 from the context options? I believe that's the answer (along with SNI), but I don't know Indy or how to do it. For reference, here's how it would look in C: [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client#Implementation). ([SSLscan](http://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) will tell if its TLS 1.2 only , or TLS 1.0 and above).

Comment: @jww: Setting the `Method` to `sslvTLSv1_2` or the `SSLVersions` to `[sslvTLSv1_2]` will automatically disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 and use a TLS-only context.

Comment: @Remy, @jww, @smooty86: I edited my question and post unit I used.
@Remy: As you can see I set `Method` to `sslvTLSv1_2`, but it does not help. May be problem is in my OS X environment? I will try WireShark to see difference

Comment: @Oleg are you *required* to use TLS 1.2 only? If not, have you tried enabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1? Also, you are leaking the SSLIOHandler object, since you are not freeing it or setting the HTTP object as its Owner.

Comment: @Remy: I use only TLS 1.2, at least I specify so. Thanks for  SSLIOHandler object suggestion

Comment: @Remy: I edit my question with WireShark details.

Comment: @Remy: Also I tried to enable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 like this:
`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(IdHTTP.IOHandler).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];`
but without any success.

Comment: @Oleg: that is the correct way to enable multiple versions. Notice that Safari is maxed out at TLS 1.0, not TLS 1.2.  A lot of servers don't really support TLS 1.1+ yet, so it is not uncommon to see TLS 1.0 still being used.  What you didn't show, though, is the capture of the TLS alert. That has a severity level and an error code to explain why the alert is being sent.

Comment: @Remmy: I added TLS alert to question

Comment: @Remmy: I corrected my question. I messed up wireshark result, must be vice versa. Safary use TLS 1.2 and my application 1.0

Comment: @Oleg: If you have your app set to enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 in the `SSLVersions`, but the handshake is only using TLS 1.0, then you are using an OpenSSL version that does not support TLS 1.1+.  Check with the `IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_1_Available()` and `IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_2_Available()` functions in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders()` unit.

Comment: @Remmy: Thank you for your advice. I tested all IsOpenSSL_% functions and found that TLS is not available at all. After that I found OpenSSLVersion function, and when I call it I get `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh`, but when I run `openssl version` in terminal I get `OpenSSL 1.0.2h`. Why? How can I use newer version and not the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after many days of research I found how to solve my problem.

To ensure application uses last version of OpenSSL libraries, that not depend on installed in OS X, I found that I can include compiled OpenSSL libraries in application package.

In my case I need x86 compiled version of openSSL libraries. 
Homebrew and Macport when installing last openssl, compile x64 version of the libraries, that's why using this link:

[Compilation and Installation of OpenSSL libraries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#OS_X)

I compiled x86 version of openSSL libraries.

Next thanks to [Marco Cantu tech Blog](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/using_ssl_delphi_ios.html), I found that I can use `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath` method to set openssl libraries path.

Finally, including compiled libraries with application in same package and using this code:

```
IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)));
```

I get correct version of openssl libraries, that support TLSv1.2

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and this seems like the correct fix, but  I can't seem to compile the libraries properly. libcrypto seems alright, but the libssl I'm getting fails in LoadLibrary ... Could you maybe upload the dylibs you ended up using somewhere, if you still have access?

Comment: I also need them, please upload them.