# OS X PATH variable in application

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I have an application that use OpenSSL to connect to some webservice.
WebService use SSL using TLS 1.2, so to connect to server I need last version of OpenSSL.

I installed last version of OpenSSL using MacPort and Homebrew.
This is result of running in terminal openssl version command:

> `Admins-Mac:~ Admin$ openssl version`
>
> `OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016`
>
> `Admins-Mac:~ Admin$ which openssl`
>
> `/opt/local/bin/openssl`
>
> `Admins-Mac:~ Admin$ echo $PATH`
>
> `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

But when I run my application, I get version 0.9 of OpenSSL
Also when I get in my application PATH environment variable I get:

> `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

That is different from PATH variable from terminal.

How to get correct PATH variable in my application to access latest OpenSSL libraries.

Comment: What is the application? How does the application use SSL - why do you think it is affected by your PATH? Does it use `system()` to exec something? Why did you install OpenSSL via MacPorts **AND** homebrew - wouldn't you be better using one or the other package manager rather than both?

Comment: It is application I develop. When I say that I installed using MacPortand Homebrew, I mean that I try to install one computer using MacPort and on arcond using Homebrew. What package manager you will recommend? I think it is affected by the PATH because when I want to get PATH variable valuefrom my app, I get different  value than terminal returnec

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @Oleg - If your probalem is regarding runtime linking (rather than an OS X path variable), then we need to see your compile/link commands for your application. We also need to see the output of `otool -L`. Brew should use `-install_name`, so the application's runtime linking to OpenSSL should be OK. The problem is likely with your compile/link command.

Comment: Answer is in this question [EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError and “Error connecting with SSL. error:14094410…”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093781/eidosslunderlyingcryptoerror-and-error-connecting-with-ssl-error14094410/39499131#39499131)