# Lazarus + Indy + Mac + OpenSSL = SSL error on CloudFlare websites

Tags: ssl, indy, lazarus

I am using Lazarus 1.6.4 on macOS Sierra 10.12.3 with newest Indy HTTP library (updated today) generating a 32bit carbon application.

My program defaults to use Apple supplied **libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib** and **libssl.0.9.8.dlib** in **/usr/lib/** ...

I get error

> Project .... raised exception class 'EIdOSSUnderlyingCryptoError' with
>   message; Error connecting with SSL. error:14077410:SSL
>   rouines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

What is the most reliable way to solve this problem?

My code is like this:

```
    TmpOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
    // have had code rotate between
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv23]; 
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Metod := sslvSSLv23; 
    //
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2]; 
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Metod := sslvTLSv1_2; 
    //
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1]; 
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Metod := sslvTLSv1_1; 
    //
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_0]; 
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Metod := sslvTLSv1_0; 
    //
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    TmpOpenSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    W.IOHandler := TmpOpenSSL;
```

No matter which used, I get the above error which is... kinda odd

I would prefer not to distribute OpenSSL myself - but rather use something supplied by Mac OS *or* if I must - something that is very easy to install even for non-expert users

Note: Windows10 + Lazarus 1.6.4 + Indy (newest) + OpenSSL (newest fulgan binaries) work

...

I believe this is related

[EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875664/)

where the issue is resolved in newest version of Indy on Windows, but not on Mac (possible because of the OpenSSL library version on Mac)

Comment: OpenSSL 0.x? Oh that's too old...

Comment: unforunate :( Just annoying that is what Apple ships with. I was hoping Apple maybe kept the 0.9.8 name, but actually maintained/patched it or something. It still works for majority of SSL websites, but not cloudflare SSL it seems

Comment: Each version of Indy library supports specific version on ssl-library. I can suggest you to try different version of ssl libraries. You have to put those in program's directory to check if it works one by one

Comment: I have with success used different verions of OpenSSL - true I encountered a problem now with CloudFlare SSL websites, but otherwise same Indy version using 0.9.8 on Mac and new OpenSSL versions on Windows

Comment: @AlexSlipknot: that is not true.  Each version of Indy is not locked in to a specific version of OpenSSL.  Indy operates on OpenSSL's public interface, it doesn't care about specific versions.  As long as the OpenSSL libs export the functions Indy is interested in using, you can switch between OpenSSL versions.

Comment: `sslv3 alert` means the server is rejecting the handshake and sending an alert packet to the client before closing the connection. Without knowing exactly what the server is actually rejecting, you won't be able to troubleshoot this on the client side.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau , I know it shouldn't be. But in fact I succeeded with some specific version of libeay / ssleay

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will try on Mac using a newer OpenSSL version. From my research the 0.9.8 version supplied by Apple gets security patches and is actually more of a custom OpenSSL library - but I am no expert at OpenSSL - just something I read. If it works with new OpenSSL library I guess the problem is not solveable. If it does not work with new OpenSSL library on Mac but otherwise same code/Indy/Lazarus in Mac and Wndows then maybe there is hope. I believe the problem is related to some changes CloudFlare made. (If anyone has suggestions for Indy settings I can try, let me know - I report back)

Comment: @RemyLebeau For what it is worth - it does not appear to work using 1.0.2g either (homebrew openssl) on mac/lazarus/indy combo. In the linked SO, someone also reported problems on Delphi/mac/indy combo after the issue was fixed on Windows. (But I do not know the problems are exactly the same)

Comment: For refefence I believe problem affects all websites with: Cloudflare ssl option without SSL certificate on the server - probably relaed to a SNI problem of a sorts

Comment: The latest Indy uses SNI on the client side when connecting to a server. Without specific details about why this is failing, there is nothing I can do about it.

Comment: @Remy I understand. I can confirm it works on Windows - just odd not on Mac - at least not with the setup I tested. I will report back if I find anything.

Comment: You might try using a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to compare the SSL/TLS handshakes on Windows and Mac to see what is different between them.

Comment: Which EXACT version of OpenSSL 0.9.8 are you using?  SNI support (and support for TLS extensions in general) was added in 0.9.8f, and even then it was disabled by default unless OpenSSL was compiled with the "enable-tlsext" option.  CloudFlare may be rejecting the handshake if SNI is not being used.

Comment: It is my understanding that 0.9.8 on Mac is actually a continuous security patched custom OpenSSL library by Apple (I read it e.g. integrates with keychain/certificates) - but the date of it 13 December 2016 - however, I will see if I can find out more about this.

Comment: @Remy do you know if OpenSSL works on Delphi/Mac with Indy? I am just puzzled since I tried with 1.0.2g as well from Homebrew. But I will try with a newer version later. For reference, I have version 0.9.8zh from 14 Jan 2016 (in terminal I type "openssl version -a" and "which openssl")

Comment: @Tom AFAIK, it should be working

Comment: @Tom `libsys` is not a filename that Indy looks for when loading OpenSSL libraries at runtime

Comment: @RemyLebeau

Sorry, I mistyped in my comment yesterday as I was comparing file names (working/typing on Windows but looking at a Mac computer - seems I messed up multiple things).

Here are the proper files:

---- libcrypto.dylib, libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib, libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib, libcrypto.35.dylib, libcrypto.0.41.dylib ----

---- libssl.dylib, libssl.0.9.7.dylib, libssl.0.9.8.dylib, libssl.35.dylib,  libssl.0.41.dylib ----

I can now duplicate the problem on other non-cloudflare SSL solutions as well. Few days old Indy + few days old Lazarus SVN + newest macOS pointing indy to /usr/lib/

Comment: @RemyLebeau
Seems macOS now points to LibreSSL since libcrypto.dylib points to libcrypto.35.dylib (and similar for libssl.dylib) which I can read online is LibreSSL and not OpenSSL.

Remy do you have any ideas... Should I point Indy explicitly to point to 0.9.8 dylib versions?

Comment: @Tom Indy doesn't provide an option to specify the exact filenames, only the folder. It then runs through a list of pre-defined filenames until it finds a match. Changing that logic would require altering Indy's source code and recompiling. If you want to use a specific version of OpenSSL (1.0.2 is the latest supported by Indy), you should put those dylibs in a folder of your choosing, then specify that folder path to Indy via the `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function at app startup. Apple has deprecated support for OpenSSL on OSX, so you have to deploy newer OpenSSL versions with your app

Comment: @RemyLebeau That may be the only solution - I was just hoping for a solution using the built-in openssl/libressl files provided by Apple (to avoid shipping openssl libs myself)